# Persistent dark/light while browsing other pages

Tags: javascript

This question has been asked a lot but I just can't find a straightforward example on to deal with my scenario. I have a simple, basic dark mode set by default. I use the following to toggle between the two modes.

```
document.querySelector('.theme-switch').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('light-theme')
})
```

I need to save the user selection so that it doesn't switch back when navigating to other pages. Here's what I have tried but couldn't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
document.querySelector('.theme-switch').addEventListener('click', () => {
   document.body.classList.toggle('light-theme')        
    })

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const selection = document.querySelector('.theme-switch');

  selection.checked = localStorage.getItem('light-theme') === 'true';
  document.body.classList.toggle('light-theme', selection.checked);

  selection.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    localStorage.setItem('light-theme', event.currentTarget.checked);
    
  });
});
```

Comment: `selelection` and `selection` appear to be undefined.   Should those not be `sel`?

Comment: Your only ever changing the theme on your click event, you just need to do also in your DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks, I made the edit.

Comment: @Keith Thanks, could you please post a working example so I can accept your answer?

Comment: @Keith Please reply with an answer.

Comment: @Cosmin  Ok, done..

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately creating a working snippet in Stack Overflow is not possible, as localStorage is disallowed as it's sandboxed.

But all you should need to do is also put the below code into your DOMContentLoaded,.

```
document.body.classList.toggle('light-theme', selection.checked);
```

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work. It keeps changing back to the original when switching between pages. What am I doing wrong? Please see update post above. PS: light-theme should be off by default.

Comment: @Cosmin With your browsers inspector tools what does localeStorage have stored.?

Comment: It says light-theme: undefined | darkmode: false